# Use of python in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

All I'm looking for is a multi-platform python-independent way of, say, printing "hi" on the screen using Python, but in an HTML file

Comment: How can it be Python-independent if you're using Python?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want to check out [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) and [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/).

Comment: I checked both of them. Pyjamas are no supported in chrome.

Comment: Ok. Check out Pyjamas FAQ for info about the Chrome issue (http://pyjs.org/#FAQ). I hope Skulpt fits your bill. It should work at least for that "hi" case. :)

Comment: @Ambika: What do you mean by "Pyjamas are no supported in chrome." For example, http://pyjs.org/examples/libtest/output/LibTest.html produces the same results on Firefox 3.6.15 and Google Chrome 7.0.517.41 Pyjamas (among other things) contains port of Google Web Toolkit in Python. Click see demo at http://pyjs.org/examples/ e.g., http://pyjs.org/examples/kitchensink/output/KitchenSink.html